# Action Handler and Widgets in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a GWT project that has some menu items. These menu items are created by using Anchor widgets in GWT. But all Action Handlers adeed to these anchors are not seems to be firing on any event that occurs.

What may be the problem? Please give me some head start to debug the problem?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you're trying to do and what part of it isn't working?

Comment: Which action handlers are you referring to? ClickHandlers? Can you put your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [specific constructor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#Anchor%28java.lang.String%29) of the Anchor widget to enable scripting on it.

If you use UiBinder then add `href="javascript:;"` to Anchor:

```
<g:Anchor href="javascript:;">
```